Prisma unable to connect to the database during Docker build time
Issue: Prisma unable to connect to the database during Docker build time
Context

Environment: Dokku
Database: Dokku-managed PostgreSQL instance
Application: Next.js

Steps

Created a PostgreSQL database using Dokku.
Linked the database to the Next.js application using Dokku.

Error
During the Docker build process, the following error is encountered:
Can't reach database server at `dokku-postgres-xyz`:`5432`. Please make sure your database server is running at `dokku-postgres-xyz`:`5432`

This error suggests that Prisma is unable to connect to the database during the build time of the Docker container.
Attempted Solution
I tried to make the PostgreSQL database publicly accessible and connect to it by updating the Dockerfile using build arguments. This approach worked, but I don't want to expose my PostgreSQL database publicly for security reasons.
Question
Is there a solution to resolve this issue and allow Prisma to connect to the database during the Docker build process?

Docker containers are not on the Docker network during the build process. Only at run-time. So you need to have a Postgres instance available in some other way during the build process.
